# Как настроить получение значений по расписанию в Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

Хочу настроить получение значения по расписанию в Zabbix, но не получается.
Чтобы было понятнее, я хочу получать метрики, сколько страниц распечатано на принтере с начала текущего дня и с начала текущего месяца.
Общее количество распечатанных страниц получать я умею, получаю его по стандартному расписанию раз в 10 минут (Update interval: 10m). Чтобы получить данные на начало дня и на начало месяца, я создаю ещё два элемента с пользовательскими интервалами по расписанию md/1 (начало дня) и md1 (начало месяца); Update interval оставляю 1m (убрать его нельзя, это обязательное поле), но Zabbix c такими установками обновляет данные по элементу каждую минуту.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно решить мою задачу?

Answer (score 0):

В общем, всё оказалось просто, нужно установить для Update interval значение 0 и тогда начнёт отрабатывать пользовательский интервал.